# Retrieve tags from xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I have employee data in employeedata.xml file. My sample data looks like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <DocumentElement>
      <_x005B_dbo_x005D_._x005B_employeedata_x005D_>
        <RowID>11148</RowID>
        <ItemID>966109</ItemID>
        <Mappings>[]</Mappings>
        <Groups>93664,68349</Groups>
        <GroupKey>7003142</GroupKey>
        <ParentItemID>351908</ParentItemID>
        <JobID>30318</JobID>
        <Action>Employee</Action>
        <Employee_Name>John Travis</Employee_Name>
        <mail_id>John@altmail.com</mail_id>
        <...>...</...>  
        <Action>Experience</Action>
        <...>...</...>
        <...>...</...>
        <...>...</...>
```

I'm using python 3.8.10 to read the file. I'm using following code to read my data

```
with open('employeedata.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

I would like to store my xml in pandas data frame where the value under tag `Action` will store in `Action` column & corresponding tag will store in other column, `Field`. My sample output will look like

```
|    Action    |    Field    |
|--------------|-------------|
|    Employee  |Employee_Name|
|    Employee  |mail_id      |
|    Employee  |....         |
|    Employee  |....         |
|    Experience|....         |
|    Experience|....         |
```

Can you please suggest me how should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this [python xml parser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml-tree-and-elements)

In your case:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('employeedata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) can read the xml file directly:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml("Employee data.xml", xpath="_x005B_dbo_x005D_._x005B_employeedata_x005D_")
print(df[['Action', 'Employee_Name']].to_string(index=False))
```

If you like you can also print do at the whole.

Output:

```
Action Employee_Name
Experience   John Travis
```